# Lucky Bamboo turning yellow starting from the bottom

Tags: houseplants, lucky-bamboo

I have problem with my lucky bamboo. I had notice that it was turning yellow and I had cut where I think I'm supposed to. I think your supposed to cut about 1-2 inches above the notch. I had cut it thinking that I had cut it right. I put wax on the bottom to protect it. My question is do I put the lucky bamboo in water with the wax on the bottom in water or do I turn it upside down where the top is in the water.. not sure what to do?

Comment: this link leads to some great answers about lucky bamboo and will help http://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=lucky+bamboo

Comment: Don't think it's a dupe of your linked question @kevinsky That plant appears to be root-bound, and if I read this question right, this one was just re-potted.

Comment: @GardenerJ It sounds like it was repotted because the leaves were turning yellow.  If the "root" issue is fungus or spider mites or root bound or other causes then the other answers cover this.

Comment: @kevinsky maybe I'm confused then, I was thinking it sounds like the plant was re-potted and then it turned yellow.

Comment: @GardenerJ  No pictures and not much explanation in the question make answering this a challenge